# A functional analysis exam question

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be the metric space and it is not a compact set.Show that

$(1)$There is $\varepsilon>0$ and the sequence $\left\{ x_n \right\}\subset X$ ,when $m\ne n$,there is$$B\left( x_n,\varepsilon \right) \cap B\left( x_m,\varepsilon \right)=\oslash.$$
$(2)$There is a continuous function $f_n(x):X\longrightarrow \left[ \text{0,}1 \right]$ for any $n$,such that 
$$f_n(x_{n})=1$$if and only if $x\notin B\left( x,\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \right)$,there is$f_n(x)=0.$

I worked hard but didn't solve it.I started from a definition that is not compact set, but I don't know how to find the sequence $\left\{ x_n \right\}$.So I hope you can give me some ideas.

Comment: Part (1) is only true if the space $X$ is also assumed to _complete_.

Answer (score 0):

You need extra hypothesis for $(1)$. For example consider the open interval $(0,1)$. Because the mention to 'functional analysis' in the title I suppose that $X$ is an infinite dimensional normed space or similar.